# navigationdrawer with custom listviews and nonlistview items

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I was using ActionsContentView library for a side menu bar.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sample.actionscontentview

Initially I tried using Google's NavigationDrawer object in the support library. But I backed away from it because I needed a non-listview kind of layout for some parts of the view.

Anyway, I am wondering if this reasoning was flawed. Part of my menu is using a non-listview and some fairly intricate custom layouts, which may be added dynamically in a scrollview OR may end up being a custom adapter in a listview after all.

Regardless, I need the flexibility the ActionsContentView library already provides

Can I use non listviews in a NavigationDrawer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can.

DrawerLayout is a layout that contains 2 layouts - 1 is the menu, and the other holds thee content.

This means you can put a fragment in the menu drawer and populate that with whatever content you want.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/backgound_menu" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
            android:name="com.foo.bar.fragment.MenuFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/menu_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You can do this through a base activity class which your menu activities extend. Then add a setFrameContent method in the base activity which will populate the activity frame with the content fragment. In your subclasses call setFrameContent instead of setConentView in the onCreate method.

Base Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_drawer);
}

public void setFrameContent(int activityLayout) {
    mContent.addView(
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    activityLayout,
                    mContent, false),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

Subclass

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_content);
}
```

From there you are free to do whatever with the MenuFragment.

Comment: Can you give a full example @Phil H